# Python: Facebook Graph API search by name

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know this is really simple, but I cannot figure it out. Trying to search for a user by name.

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
graph.request(#HAVING PROBLEMS)
```

from the documentation:

```
def request(self, path, args=None, post_args=None, files=None, method=None)
```

`graph.request('/search')` got that part. Response is  `no node specified`.

If I try `graph.request('/search', 'any string at all')`, for example:

```
graph.request('/search', 'my name') #or
graph.request('/search', 'name=whatever')
```

I get:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facebook.py", line 291, in request
    args["access_token"] = self.access_token
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: args should be a dict and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me:

```
import facebook
token = 'my_token'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
data = graph.request('/search?q=someusernane&type=user')
print data
```